# ASP.NET Core Serialize all Enums to UpperCase

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have enum in ASP.NET application. e.g.:

```
 public enum Status
        {
            Active,
            Inactive,
            Offline
        }
```

I want to return these Enum values as UpperCase in API response:

e.g. Status: "INACTIVE" instead of Status: "Inactive"

Tried following code, but it does not really do anything:

```
 public sealed class EnumUpperCaseConverter<TEnum> : JsonConverter<TEnum?> where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        public override TEnum? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                string enumValue = reader.GetString();
                if (Enum.TryParse(enumValue, true, out TEnum result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            throw new JsonException($"Unable to parse enum from {reader.TokenType}");
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            string enumValue = value?.ToString().ToUpper();
            writer.WriteStringValue(enumValue);
        }
    }
```

I also register this to Program.cs, but it does not work:

```
 builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EnumUpperCaseConverter<>());
        });
```

Is there simpler way to do this? Or will I need to just Change all Enum values to UpperCase?

Comment: First of all you should not add `JsonStringEnumConverter`.

Comment: JsonStringEnumConverter takes a  JsonNamingPolicy. There are predefined classes for Camel,Snake,Kebab etc. but no UpperCase (thats uncommon). Should be easy to implement. Derive from JsonNamingPolicy and implement ConvertName see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy?view=net-7.0